# Laravel Form Class without second argument

Tags: php, forms, laravel, autocomplete

I simply want to give the text element of my edit-form a class.

```
{{ Form::text('first_name') }}
```

I know that i have to use an array with the class of the field as third argument. But i do NOT want to give a second argument. This one

```
{{ Form::text('first_name' , ' ' , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

applys the class correctly, but sets the dafault value to an empty string. This is a problem, because now laravels auto-complete function doesn't fill the form with the correct data from the database. Is there a way to give no second argument or setting it to default like this?

```
{{ Form::text('first_name' , default , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Thanks!

Comment: None, but i want to give the textfield a class

Comment: I replaced your ''' by ''. So i now have
    {{ Form::text('first_name' , isset($value)?$value:'' , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

but this still doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, i solved it myself. It is as easy as it always is. Simply use

```
{{ Form::text('first_name' , null , array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```